# Issues in creating J2C Java beans using the Batch Import Utility in WAS 8.5

Tags: websphere, jax-rpc, cics, ibm-rad-7.5, wsad5.1

I'm facing issues in creating **J2C Java beans** using the **Batch Import Utility**.

In my project I have a custom ANT Build file which invokes **ImportBatch.bat** file of WSAD 5.1 Plugin. In WAS 5.1 it is working fine but in WAS 8.5 using Rational Application Developer 9.5 the same utility throws **NullPointerException**.

As per my analysis WAS 5.1 has "*com.ibm.etools.ctc.import.batch_5.1.1*" plugin which is used to perform the above task. I searched for this plugin in WAS 8.5 and I got that it has been changed to "*com.ibm.adapter.j2c.command_6.2.700.v20150320_0049*" plugin. It has the same *importBatch.bat* file. 
Also I've to change importBatch file as per the current RAD 9.5 jar "equinox Launcher" because RAD 9.5 has no startup.jar

**The original entry in RAD 9.5 importBatch.bat file**:-

```
"%eclipse_root%\jre\bin\java" -Xmx256M -verify -Dimport.batch.cp="%currentCodepage%" -cp "%eclipse_root%\startup.jar" 
org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main -clean -data "%workspace%" -application com.ibm.adapter.j2c.command.BatchImport -file=%import_file% -style=%generation_style%
```

**changes I've made:-**

```
"%eclipse_root%\jdk\jre\bin\java" -Xmx256M -verify -Dimport.batch.cp="%currentCodepage%" -cp "%eclipse_root%\plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar" org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main -clean -data "%workspace%" -application 
com.ibm.adapter.j2c.command.BatchImport -file=%import_file% -style=%generation_style%
```

I've gone through the IBM Knowledge center for this topic but still no success.
http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS4JCV_7.5.5/com.ibm.etools.j2c.doc/topics/tusingbatchimporter.html

Please have a look at the exception that I'm getting in workspace logs.

```
    !SESSION 2016-08-20 14:07:55.714 -----------------------------------------------
    eclipse.buildId=unknown
    java.fullversion=JRE 1.8.0 IBM J9 2.8 Windows 7 amd64-64 Compressed References 20150630_255633 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)
    J9VM - R28_jvm.28_20150630_1742_B255633
    JIT  - tr.r14.java_20150625_95081.01
    GC   - R28_jvm.28_20150630_1742_B255633_CMPRSS
    J9CL - 20150630_255633
    BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_GB

    !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2016-08-20 14:07:57.403
    !MESSAGE The -clean (osgi.clean) option was not successful. Unable to clean the storage area: C:\Program Files\IBM\SDP

\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi

    !ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.registry 2 0 2016-08-20 14:10:05.082
    !MESSAGE The extensions and extension-points from the bundle "org.eclipse.emf.commonj.sdo" are ignored. The bundle is not 

marked as singleton. 

    !ENTRY org.eclipse.core.resources 2 10035 2016-08-20 14:10:54.180
    !MESSAGE The workspace exited with unsaved changes in the previous session; refreshing workspace to recover changes.

    !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2016-08-20 14:10:55.789
    !MESSAGE Application error
    !STACK 1
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.ibm.adapter.j2c.command.internal.batchimport.BatchImportApplication.copyTestBucket(BatchImportApplication.java:140)
        at com.ibm.adapter.j2c.command.internal.batchimport.BatchImportApplication.run(BatchImportApplication.java:118)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppContainer.callMethodWithException(EclipseAppContainer.java:587)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:198)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1438)

    !ENTRY com.ibm.etools.references 4 0 2016-08-20 14:10:56.147
    !MESSAGE Framework stop [EXCEPTION] Exception during shutdown. Indexer will be rebuilt on next startup.
    !STACK 0
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.ibm.etools.references.internal.management.InternalReferenceManager.hasStar(InternalReferenceManager.java:1394)
        at com.ibm.etools.references.internal.management.InternalReferenceManager$ShutdownCode.call

(InternalReferenceManager.java:175)
        at com.ibm.etools.references.internal.management.InternalReferenceManager$ShutdownCode.call

(InternalReferenceManager.java:1)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:267)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1143)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:618)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:785)
        at com.ibm.etools.references.internal.ReferenceThreadFactrory$ReferencesThread.run(ReferenceThreadFactrory.java:37)

    !ENTRY com.ibm.etools.references 4 0 2016-08-20 14:10:56.153
    !MESSAGE [SCR] Error while attempting to deactivate instance of component Component[
        name = Reference Manager
        activate = activate
        deactivate = deactivate
        modified = 
        configuration-policy = optional
        factory = null
        autoenable = true
        immediate = true
        implementation = com.ibm.etools.references.management.ReferenceManager
        state = Disabled
        properties = 
        serviceFactory = false
        serviceInterface = [com.ibm.etools.references.management.ReferenceManager]
        references = {
            Reference[name = IWorkspace, interface = org.eclipse.core.resources.IWorkspace, policy = static, cardinality = 

1..1, target = null, bind = null, unbind = null]
            Reference[name = IPreferencesService, interface = org.eclipse.core.runtime.preferences.IPreferencesService, policy 

= static, cardinality = 1..1, target = null, bind = null, unbind = null]
            Reference[name = ThreadSupport, interface = com.ibm.etools.references.internal.ThreadSupport, policy = static, 

cardinality = 1..1, target = null, bind = addThreadSupport, unbind = removeThreadSupport]
            Reference[name = EventAdmin, interface = org.osgi.service.event.EventAdmin, policy = static, cardinality = 1..1, 

target = null, bind = addEventAdmin, unbind = removeEventAdmin]
        }
        located in bundle = com.ibm.etools.references_1.2.400.v20150320_0049 [732]
    ]
    !STACK 0
    java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.deactivate(ServiceComponent.java:363)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.deactivate(ServiceComponentProp.java:161)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.dispose(ServiceComponentProp.java:387)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.dispose(ServiceComponentProp.java:102)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.disposeInstances(InstanceProcess.java:366)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.disposeInstances(InstanceProcess.java:306)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.disposeComponentConfigs(Resolver.java:724)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.disableComponents(Resolver.java:700)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.stoppingBundle(SCRManager.java:554)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.bundleChanged(SCRManager.java:233)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:902)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEventPrivileged(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:165)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEvent(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:75)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEvent(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:67)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainerAdaptor.publishModuleEvent(EquinoxContainerAdaptor.java:102)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.publishEvent(Module.java:466)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStop(Module.java:624)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.stop(Module.java:488)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.decStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1623)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1542)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.SystemModule.stopWorker(SystemModule.java:248)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$SystemBundle$EquinoxSystemModule.stopWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:145)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStop(Module.java:626)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.stop(Module.java:488)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.SystemModule.stop(SystemModule.java:186)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$SystemBundle$EquinoxSystemModule$1.run(EquinoxBundle.java:160)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:785)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.ibm.etools.references.internal.management.InternalReferenceManager.deactivate(InternalReferenceManager.java:1153)
        at com.ibm.etools.references.management.ReferenceManager.deactivate(ReferenceManager.java:321)
        ... 33 more
    Root exception:
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.ibm.etools.references.internal.management.InternalReferenceManager.deactivate(InternalReferenceManager.java:1153)
        at com.ibm.etools.references.management.ReferenceManager.deactivate(ReferenceManager.java:321)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.deactivate(ServiceComponent.java:363)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.deactivate(ServiceComponentProp.java:161)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.dispose(ServiceComponentProp.java:387)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.dispose(ServiceComponentProp.java:102)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.disposeInstances(InstanceProcess.java:366)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.disposeInstances(InstanceProcess.java:306)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.disposeComponentConfigs(Resolver.java:724)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.disableComponents(Resolver.java:700)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.stoppingBundle(SCRManager.java:554)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.bundleChanged(SCRManager.java:233)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:902)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEventPrivileged(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:165)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEvent(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:75)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEvent(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:67)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainerAdaptor.publishModuleEvent(EquinoxContainerAdaptor.java:102)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.publishEvent(Module.java:466)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStop(Module.java:624)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.stop(Module.java:488)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.decStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1623)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1542)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.SystemModule.stopWorker(SystemModule.java:248)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$SystemBundle$EquinoxSystemModule.stopWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:145)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStop(Module.java:626)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.stop(Module.java:488)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.SystemModule.stop(SystemModule.java:186)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$SystemBundle$EquinoxSystemModule$1.run(EquinoxBundle.java:160)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:785)
```

Comment: One more point needs to be mentioned here is that ImportBatch utility has the capability to convert Cobol copybooks to wsdl files and placing them in folder wise structure. Is there any other similar utility in RAD 9.5/ WAS 8.5 plugins then please let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a problem for IBM support, I suggest you raise a PMR via the IBM support process to get a solution to this issue.

Comment: Hey @Phil Wakelin Thanks for your reply. I'll raise a PMR. Meanwhile can I have any workaround to this approach? It would be really helpful for me if you have any alternative approach to this.