# Warning message:WSWS3770W on converting WSDL2Java in RAD 9.5

Tags: java, xml, web-services, wsdl, ibm-rad

I'm getting warning message in WSDL2Java Conversion.

WSWS3770W: Warning: WSDL2Java does not support http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/formatbinding/ binding namespace

The wsdl file used is given below. Any help in this regard would be highly appreciated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions name="StockQuoteServiceJava"
targetNamespace="http:///"
    xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
    xmlns:format="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/formatbinding/"
    xmlns:java="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/java/"
    xmlns:tns="http:///"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <import location="StockQuoteService.wsdl"
namespace="http:///"/>
    <binding name="StockQuoteServiceJavaBinding"
type="tns:StockQuoteService">
        <java:binding/>
        <format:typeMapping encoding="Java" style="Java">
            <format:typeMap formatType="java.lang.String"
typeName="xsd:string"/>
            <format:typeMap formatType="float"
typeName="xsd:float"/>
        </format:typeMapping>
        <operation name="getQuote">
            <java:operation methodName="getQuote"
                parameterOrder="symbol" returnPart="result"/>
            <input name="getQuoteRequest"/>
            <output name="getQuoteResponse"/>
        </operation>
    </binding>
    <service name="StockQuoteServiceService">
        <port binding="tns:StockQuoteServiceJavaBinding"
name="StockQuoteServiceJavaPort">
            <java:address className="StockQuoteService"/>
        </port>
    </service>
</definitions>
```

Comment: Rewrite your wsdl without using `xmlns:format="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/formatbinding/"` as it is not supported.

Comment: Hi @Gas Thanks for your prompt reply. I would like to mention here that if I do remove xmlns:format="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/formatbinding/" from the wsdl file then I won't be able to use <format:typeMapping > elements in my wsdl. The wsdl  I mentione above was just for sample. In actual I have to use format type mapping as below:<format:typeMapping encoding="ibmcobol">
            <format:typeMap formatType="GetHomeQuoteBinding" typeName="interface1:ABC"/>
 </format:typeMapping>

Comment: I have gone through a weblink for this mapping extension [link](https://ws.apache.org/wsif/providers/wsdl_extensions/formattypemapping_extension.pdf)   How could I use this in my environment - JDK 1.7, WAS 8.5, RAD 9.5 The WSDL was working fine in legacy environment- WAS 5.1, JDK 1.4.    Is there any schema xsd file that I can import into my project to get this working.

Comment: You probably had WSAD-IE and WBISF, where such mappings were used, not plain WAS 5.1. I don't know any details, but you can check [Migrating J2C programs using the Java Connector migration tool](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSRTLW_9.5.0/com.ibm.j2c.doc/topics/tmigprojj2cmigrationtool.html) or try to run your app as is in WAS 8.5 and see what errors will show up.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Gas I'll check the link shared by you and get back to you in case of any issue. Meanwhile could you please suggest your expert opinion for another question that I've posted few days back. [Issues in creating J2C Java beans using the Batch Import Utility in WAS 8.5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39147283/issues-in-creating-j2c-java-beans-using-the-batch-import-utility-in-was-8-5)  Any help in this regard would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, I don't use J2C beans and that batch utility. You should open PMR as suggested.